# Is there a onExit or onDestroy method on Phonegap 3?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova

Does Phonegap 3 includes a method "onExit" or "onDestroy" ? I would like to perform some actions before the app closes.

Basically, I want to kill an admob.

Comment: I suggest window.onunload must work this way

Answer (score 1):

Well, after some exploration seems like phonegap api have no such event as onDestroy. This functionality could be implementat in some states for android, course a bit creepy, but in iOS this is not avalible anyway.

### Android logic:

if user presses the home button app fires pause event, but application is not closed, so window.onunload will take no reaction. From this point phonegap app's webView doesn't recieve any event. But if user presses back button on first page or application was closed programmatically window.onunload must fire. I think there is a way to realise some kind of native callback by creating a java background process.

### iOS logic:

In iOS, application can't close itself by some kind of apple sequrity statements. So app never closes untill user do this by double pressing the home button and killing the app. By some reasons apple dosen't allow apps do anything in background, excluding push notification recievement. So app can detect only it's transfer from foreground to background

Answer (score 0):

I think all you have is onpause/onresume

Comment: Yes, it exists onpause/onresume, i'll try using those. Hope it's work when closing the app.